# If else with formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this giant formula which **I want to first check if it returns a zero or not.**

- If it does not return a zero, it should set cell value to something returned/set by the formula
- else it should set the cell's value to another formula values

So if,

`F1 = CONCAT(IF(EXACT(D1,E1),"""",""A, ""),IF(EXACT(F1,G1),"""",""B, ""),IF(EXACT(H1,I1),"""",""C, ""),IF(EXACT(J1,K1),"""",""D, ""),IF(EXACT(L1,M1),"""",""E, ""),IF(EXACT(N1,O1),"""",""F""))`

And

`F2 = IF(AND(ISNA(P1),ISNA(D1),ISNA(F1),ISNA(H1),ISNA(J1),ISNA(L1),ISNA(N1),CELL(""contents"",E1)<>0),""RNA"",IF(AND(ISNA(P1),ISNA(D1),ISNA(F1),ISNA(H1),ISNA(J1),ISNA(L1),ISNA(N1),CELL(""contents"",E1)=0),""Disregard"",))`

I would like to check the below

- If F1 does not return a zero
- then Set cell value to F1
- else
- set cell value to F2

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula, it should work:

`=IF(F1<>0,F1,F2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can write one more IF condition where you check F1 for zero and if not you repeat F1 formula "else" you write F2 formula.